# How to change the name of a WebService using CXF?

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf

We have a WebService, let´s call it CarLoans, which is generated by cxf based on a WSDL file. The WSDL is retrieved using the maven-resources-plugin from an external dependency. The cxf-codegen-plugin has a bindings file which we use to prefix various other elements with, for example the request and response object to the WebService. Let`s assume that we want the request and response objects to be prefixed WS and CarLoans postfixed EndPoint. How do we configure this using the bindings.xml file? The resulting java code should look roughly like this (excluding irrelevant annotations etc):

```
@WebService(targetNamespace="http://url.com/", name="CarLoansPortType")
public interface CarLoansPortType {
  public WSCarLoansResponse getCarLoans(@WebParam(name = "request") WSCarLoansRequest request)
}
```

Comment: Do you own the WSDL ?

Comment: No, unfortunately we do not.

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting link in the apache mail archives - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201202.mbox/%3CCAMHV5gYe8VQDoBfKdEP9nrg-VXy9FnA9BL_4oqpE_zKC2=-x3w@mail.gmail.com%3E

The relevant code is pasted below:

```
<jaxws:bindings 
  xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='CREATE_RECIPE']">
      <jaxws:class name="CreateRecipeSEI"/>
  </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

So basically it should be fairly easy to do. I´m experiencing some local problems with getting the XPATH expression to work, but this definitely seems to be what we were looking for.

Comment: And where is this code. Looks like WSDL bindings section to me.

Comment: Exactly. As I wrote in the OP, we want a bindings file which ensures that the generated java code representation of the porttype has a different name from the one specified in the WSDL.

Comment: This solution works, my local problem was not xpath (the code snippet above is correct) but a wrong wsdl-reference from the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing that.

What you are using is called the **'Contract First'** approach, where the web service and its data types are defined in a WSDL file. Then tools are used to generate appropriate code in a given programming language.

However, if you are the author of the WSDL in question, you need to modify the name of the data-types in WSDL. Look for data-types definitions under the `<types>` element. WSDLs are complex and you should modify them only if you know what you are doing.

Comment: We cannot edit anything in the WSDL, hence this question. As I said, the WSDL is retrieved from an external project, over which we have no control.

Comment: In that case not possible, unless you generate the classes and then go on renaming them.